# change Id/class or input name on adding rows in dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, dynamic-tables

Currently I'm working on a dynamic table where user can add and remove rows form the table to input data...how do I change my user's input 'name/id/class' on adding rows. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Dynamic table</title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-YcbK69I5IXQftf/mYD8WY0/KmEDCv1asggHpJk1trM8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <script>

        $(document).ready( function() {

           $('#butVal').click(function(){
             var rowLen =  $('tr.tabRow').length;

             if(rowLen>9)
             {
                  alert("no of row is reached 10");
             }
             else
             {
               $("tr.tabRow:first").clone(true).appendTo("#table-2>tbody"); 



            $(".tabRow:last").children("td").children("input").each(function(index, element){
                $(element).val("");
            });



            }
            });


        $(document).on("click", "button.remove", function(){

         if($(this).parents("tr").siblings("tr.tabRow").length > 0)
          {
             $(this).closest("tr.tabRow").remove();        
          }
         else
         {
            alert("you can.t remove this record");
         }
        });


            $(document).on("click", ".add, .remove", function(){

               $("td.sno").each(function(index,element){                 
                   $(element).text(index + 1); 
                });
            });
        });



    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="total">
            <table id="table-2" class="add" border ="1">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="small">S.No</th>
                    <th class="sizing"> Description</th><th>Quantity</th>
                    <th> Price </th> 
                    <th><button id="butVal"> + </button></th>
                    </tr> 
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <tr class="tabRow" id="1item">
                <td class="sno">1</td>
                <td> <input class="desc" type="text" name="desc"/>  </td>
                <td> <input class="qty" type="text" name="qty"/> </td>
                <td> <input class="price" type="text" name="price"/> </td>
                <td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the MySQL part of this?

Comment: @PeterMader I only need to change user input id/class/name on adding rows, MySQL in not my problem.

Comment: But you tagged it with `mysql`. Do you plan to save the data to a database later on?

Comment: @PeterMader yes sir, i just got recommended so i tagged it.

Comment: So, just to clarify: you want to change the attributes (`name`, `class`, ...) of the input elements? You can use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for that.

Comment: @PeterMader thank you, but i'm new to js and its not working for me.

Comment: What *exactly* do you want to change?

Comment: @PeterMader i made slightly changes to input field by adding classes to each. All I want is to increment the class on adding row as the S.No increases, like class="desc", class="qty", class="price" on row first, and similarly class="desc1", class="qty1", class="price1" on adding row second and so on

Answer (score 0):

So you have tried using ".addClass() Jquery function" or removeclass() function??

Heres an example of .addClass():

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">


 <title>addClass demo</title>
  <style>
  p {
    margin: 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .selected {
    color: blue;
  }
  .highlight {
    background: yellow;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Hello</p>
<p>and</p>
<p>Goodbye</p>

<script>
$( "p" ).last().addClass( "selected" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, whenever a new entry is created, you need to change the class attribute of the input elements:

```js
$('#butVal').click(function () {
    var rowLen =  $('tr.tabRow').length;

    if (rowLen > 9) {
      alert("no of row is reached 10");
    } else {
      $("tr.tabRow:first").clone(true).appendTo("#table-2>tbody"); 
      $(".tabRow:last").children("td").children("input").each(function (index, element) {
        var className = $(element).attr("class"); // get the current class attribute of the element
        $(element).attr("class", className + rowLen); // append the current row number to the class
        $(element).val("");
      });
    }
  });
```

*Note*: when you remove rows, the classes will not change. It could happen that you have the classes `desc`, then `desc1`, but then `desc3`.